# How redirect after registration?

Tags: users, wp-redirect

I have 2 different pages one  is for employee and other one is for employer ,
After signup I need to redirect page based on user role:-

- If user role is employee redirected to employee page

OR

- If user role is employer redirected to employer page,

Comment: The simplest way to do this is via a plugin. I use [Peter's Login Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) for this most of the time. It supports redirects based on user roles etc.

Comment: on that note theme my login is also good with this

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`register_new_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_new_user/) hook which is the last hook before WordPress perform the redirect to ***check your email*** page.

In the callback function you will get user ID, using it get the user data and check if user belongs to specific role.

Example:-

```
function wpse_228545_register_redirect( $user_id ) {
    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id); //Get the user data
    $roles = !empty($user_data->roles) ? $user_data->roles : array();
    $page_slug = '';

    if ( in_array('employee', $roles) ){
        $page_slug = 'employee';
    } else if ( in_array('employer', $roles) ) {
        $page_slug = 'employer';
    }

    if ( $page_slug ) {
        //You can use get_permalink() and get_page_by_path() 
        //if you have different URL structure Or want to change in future.
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url( $page_slug ) );
        exit;
    }

    return;
}
add_action('register_new_user', 'wpse_228545_register_redirect');
```